# When do you italicize the name of a book, article or website in APA style citations and references?

Tags: citations, writing

I am  writing a paper that is using APA Citation and I'm confused on how the in text citations are supposed to go. Do you italizize the name of the website, book, article in which you are citing? Or can it be left normal?

Comment: In APA style, typically the name of the website, book, or article is not part of the in-text citation, so it's not clear what you're asking - perhaps an example would help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

APA style does not include the website, book, or article title in the in-text citations. You would use the  (Author, year) format. The only exception is when there is no author listed. In that case, you include enough of the title to enable to reader to find the relevant entry in the references.

For example, if your article by an anonymous author is titled *Evidence of influences of Eurasian mythology in Charles Darwin's unpublished works*, published in 2010, your in-text citation might look like this; (Evidence of..., 2010). **You do not italicize the in-text citation, even when using a title which is [correctly] italicized in your reference list.**

For more information on the correct use of APA style, consult the *Publication Manual of the American Psychological Association*, Sixth edition, (2010), or check online at [the APA website.](http://apa.org/)  For quick reference, the [APA blog](http://blog.apastyle.org/) is also useful.